# Previewing IBM MobileFirst CLI-created project in browser

Tags: ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to learn how to build and manage apps using MobileFirst CLI. I am used to creating them in Eclipse via the MobileFirst Studio. In the Studio-created project, there is a `commons/` folder (and the mobilewebapp environment) which lets me preview the app via browser. Is there an equivalent way of doing this via CLI? Is this the same as running `ionic serve` because I am using Ionic.

Thanks!

MFP CLI 7.1,
Ionic 1.2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you created a CORDOVA application using MobileFirst CLI v7.1, then no there is no commons folder because you've created a Cordova app, not a MobileFirst Hybrid app.

For future compatibility, it is advised that you will create a Cordova app and not a Hybrid app.

In the Cordova app, you simply have a js and css folders and an index.html file. These are equivalent to the same js and css folders and index.html you would have in the common folder of a MobileFirst Hybrid app.